# Shared element transition not working with second activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation

Hi i am developing an app where i'm using shared element transition on textview however when i apply animation nothing happens and moreover text in other activity becomes invisible which is quite wierd i have given same transition name to both activities still i dont understand what the problem is please if someone can help me out here.

here is login activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.activities.LoginActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_name_signup"
            android:id="@+id/text_login"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/login_card"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/White"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_email"
                    >
                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/message"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:hint="Email id"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomEditText>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/card_divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/light_black"
                    />
                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_password"
                    >
                    <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomEditText>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Forgot Password?"
                android:id="@+id/text_forgot_password"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.ct.listrtrial.widget.CustomButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_button_effect"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="OR CONNECT WITH"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                >

                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.GoofleCustomImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebook_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                    android:src="@drawable/facebook"
                    />

                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.GoofleCustomImageView
                    android:id="@+id/google_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook_image"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus_1" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/login_page_curve"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="gotoregister"

                android:src="@drawable/login_page_curve" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                    android:id="@+id/or_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                    android:text="Or"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewBold
                    android:id="@+id/register_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/or_text"
                    android:text="Register"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        CustomEditText text_input_email,text_input_password;
        CustomButton login_button;
        GoofleCustomImageView google_image,facebook_image;
        ImageView login_page_curve;
        CustomTextViewMedium or_text,text_forgot_password,text_login;
        CustomTextViewBold register_text;
        View myView;
        boolean isUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        initViews();


    }

    public void initViews(){
        text_input_email = (CustomEditText)findViewById(R.id.text_input_email);
        text_input_password = (CustomEditText)findViewById(R.id.text_input_password);
        login_button = (CustomButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        google_image = (GoofleCustomImageView) findViewById(R.id.google_image);
        facebook_image = (GoofleCustomImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_image);
        login_page_curve  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.login_page_curve);
        or_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)findViewById(R.id.or_text);
        text_forgot_password = (CustomTextViewMedium)findViewById(R.id.text_forgot_password);
        register_text = (CustomTextViewBold)findViewById(R.id.register_text);
        text_login = (CustomTextViewMedium)findViewById(R.id.text_login);

    }

    public void gotoregister(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
                (LoginActivity.this,login_page_curve,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.transition_name_signup));

        startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bottom_up,R.anim.bottom_down);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case, are you running the app on an API >= 21 device?

Comment: yes i'm running the app on API >= 21

Comment: You're passing `login_page_curve` in the options, instead of the CustomTextViewMedium which has the TransitionName defined

Comment: i know even when i'm passing textview it is not working. so i thought of some experiment..

Comment: Try removing that `overridePendingTransition()`